# Prerequisites for running Visual Studio 2012 ArcGIS desktop application exe on any machine don't have ArcGIS installed

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, visual-studio, deployment

Scenario:

- i created an exe application using Visual studio 2012 ArcGIS Map Control Application.
- When running this application on any other machine which don't have ArcGIS installed on it. Its showing SystemIOFile exception and application don't open.
- This application uses Esri.ArcGIS.Version and other dll's in it.

Any Solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seem you have written an ArcEngine application. So, you must install ArcEngine Runtime on any machine you need to run your application.

ArcEngine Runtime is the minimum. You can either install ArcEngine SDK or even ArcGIS Desktop to run you application.

The Arc Application (Engine or Desktop), must match the version of sdk that you have built your application. For example if your used ArcObject SDK 10.2, then you must install ArcEngine or ArcGIS desktop 10.2 on the target machine.

And Lest you forget to license your ArcGIS Application (engine or desktop) before running your custom application.